# Using Bootstrap-Slider in Vue with Typescript

Tags: asp.net, typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a boostrap-slider on my page using a vue backend built with TypeScript and ASP net core. I'm using the standard template for Vue.js with TypeScript in ASP.NET Core.

I've imported the boostrap-slider types with

```
npm install --save @types/bootstrap-slider
```

and when I try to

```
import { Slider } from 'bootstrap-slider';
```

I get the error

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/mycomponent/mycomponent.ts:3:24 
>             TS2306: File '~~**redacted**~~/node_modules/@types/bootstrap-slider/index.d.ts' is not a module.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal you can refer to this MSDN post.
This sample demonstration will help you to setup Vue.js with TypeScript in ASP.NET Core.
Complete Description
[setup Vue.js with TypeScript in ASP.NET Core.](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/How-to-setup-Vuejs-with-ae2b05b7#content)

Sample Source Code:
[Vue.js with TypeScript in ASP.NET Core](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/How-to-setup-Vuejs-with-ae2b05b7/sourcecode?fileId=174199&pathId=1252689638)

To achieve `Boorstrap-Slider` you can use `vue-bootstrap-slider`
for further details see link: [vue-bootstrap-slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bootstrap-slider)

Comment: Thanks, I am using the default template. I just edited the main question for clarity.

Comment: I got it working with 'vue-bootstrap-slider'. It doesn't have type definitions so it only works with the flag '"noImplicitAny": false ' in 'tsconfig.json'

Comment: However, on the page '<b-form-slider ref="basic" v-model="basicValue" :min="0" :max="100" trigger-change-event></b-form-slider>' doesn't seem to render.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the type definitions don't export a module, so you can't import it. They do this because you can call the slider functions through jquery:

```
var someSlider = $("input.slider").slider();
var value = someSlider.slider('getValue');
```

These functions are properly typed because the typings are found even without any imports.

Comment: So do you suggest that I don't add the bootstrap-slider to the vue client app and just add it on the page?

Comment: Add the typings (`npm install --save-dev @types/bootstrap-slider`) if you need to access the control in your TypeScript code, just don't try to import it. Instead, use jQuery (`$(..)`) to get a reference to the control and then do with it whatever you need to.

Comment: Did my suggestion work for you? Could you mark it as such?